# Symfony2, How to add a hidden date type field to a form?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying the scenario below :

In **`myclassType`**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('day','hidden')
        ->add('date', 'hidden' ) 
        ->add('hours')
        ->add('comment','textarea')
    ;
}
```

In **`myclass`**

```
class myclass
{
    //.. Other stuff

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     *
     * @var date $date
     */
    protected $date;
}
```

While rendering I get this error :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error:
 Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in 
C:\wamp\www\PMI_sf2\app\cache\dev\twig\fb\40\8957f80f2358a6f4112c3427b387.php line 684") in
 form_div_layout.html.twig at line 171.
```

Any idea how I can make a Date type field hidden !??

Comment: Out of interest why do you want to hide it? What's the use case?

Comment: Say, for an edit form to insert the editing date in the background

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Form

```
$builder
    ->add('day','hidden')
    ->add('date',null,array( 'attr'=>array('style'=>'display:none;')) )
...
```

Comment: Note: Some browsers (e.g. IE8) won't submit the field if `display: none` is set. Use `visibility: hidden` instead.

Comment: And use 'label' => false to hide the label!!

Comment: you should not use a visibility  .css trick, but let Symfony to render the needed form

Answer (score 8):

Create a simple DataTransformer from DateTime object to string and a new form type named i.e. 'hidden_datetime' which uses the new DataTransformer and has the hidden form type as a parent.

```
<?php

namespace YourProject\YourBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class DateTimeToStringTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{

    public function __construct()
    {   
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime|null $datetime
     * @return string
     */
    public function transform($datetime)
    {
        if (null === $datetime) {
            return '';
        }       
        return $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

    /**
     * @param  string $datetimeString
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function reverseTransform($datetimeString)
    {
        $datetime = new \DateTime($datetimeString);
        return $datetime;
    }
}
```

..

```
<?php

namespace YourProject\YourBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use YourProject\YourBundle\Form\DataTransformer\DateTimeToStringTransformer;

class HiddenDateTimeType extends AbstractType
{

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'hidden_datetime';
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'hidden';
    }   

     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {   
        $transformer = new DateTimeToStringTransformer();
        $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
    }   

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        parent::setDefaultOptions($resolver);   
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        ));
    }    
}
```

register the new 'hidden_datetime' form type as a service in services.yml

```
yourproject.hidden_datetime.form.type:
    class: YourProject\YourBundle\Form\Type\HiddenDateTimeType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: hidden_datetime }
```

The new hidden_datetime type can then be used in your form:

// IN myclassType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
            ->add('createdAt','hidden_datetime')
            ->add('comment','textarea')
    ;
}
```

Comment: There is already a DateTimeTransformer existing for this purpose : `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\DateTimeToStringTransformer`

Answer (score 4):

None of the previous solutions worked with Symfony 3.3. I ended up creating a simple type:

```
<?php

namespace <YourProject>\<YourBundle>\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;

class HiddenDateTimeType extends HiddenType implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addModelTransformer($this);
    }

    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function transform($data)
    {
        return $data->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }

    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function reverseTransform($data)
    {
        try {
            return new \DateTime($data);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'hidden_datetime';
    }
}
```

Use it in your form like this:

```
<?php

namespace <YourProject>\<YourBundle>\Form;

use <YourProject>\<YourBundle>\Form\Type\HiddenDateTimeType;

class ReportType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('creationTime', HiddenDateTimeType::class, array(
                'required' => true,
            ));
    }
}
```

There is nothing to add to `services.yml`.

Comment: Slight typo in your code, it should be:  
`throw new TransformationFailedException($e->getMessage());`

Comment: @navitronic Thanks for reporting the typo. It was in the actual code and went unnoticed :-)

Comment: Luckily this solution still works in Symfony 5 :-) Just add a mew method to hide the label `public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {        parent::configureOptions($resolver); $resolver->setDefault('label', false); }` Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Even easier. Based on martti solution

Simply extends DateTimeType and define parent as 'hidden'.

```
<?php

namespace YourProject\YourBundle\Form\Type\HiddenDateTimeType

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;

class HiddenDateTimeType extends DateTimeType
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'hidden_datetime';
    }

    public function getParent(array $options)
    {
        return 'hidden';
    }
}
```

Register form type as a service :

```
yourproject.hidden_datetime.form.type:
    class: YourProject\YourBundle\Form\Type\HiddenDateTimeType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: hidden_datetime }
```

And you will have full access to all specific DateTimeType options

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('from' , 'hidden_date', array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'Y-m-d',
            'label' => 'popin.from',
            'required' => true
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control form output more directly than this. It's quite easy to theme specific fields. There are two steps. You need to make sure the form field is expecting a single string representation of the date. So set the date widget to `single_text`. Then override the date field to output a hidden field instead of a text field.

**Form**

```
$builder->add('date', 'date', array('widget' => 'single_text'));
```

**Twig**

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{# Makes all dates hidden, you can also name your field specifically #}
{% block date_row %}
    {{ block('hidden_widget') }} {# This is normally 'field_widget' #}
{% endblock %}
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming

Comment: This still works with Symfony 3.4, but you need to override the type.
{%- set type = 'hidden' -%}

Answer (score 0):

Form

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options){
    $builder
        ->add('day','hidden')
        ->add('date') 
        ->add('hours')
        ->add('comment','textarea');
}
```

View:

```
<form action="{{ path('some-save-action') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    <div style="display: none">
         {{ form_row(form.date) }}
    </div>

    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button confirm big"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I liked the idea, But is there any support for that in Symfony2 ?

Comment: Don't thinks so... @a.aitboudad have alternative solution, but if you containing DIV is styled, it'll still be visible.

You also can extend default Symfony field type to add option hidden and extend form block "form_row", to add style="display: none" on containing DIV - if you use DIV layout